# UIButton icons on UIBarbutton

Tags: iphone

Is there any easy way to use the UIButton icons (UIButtonTypeInfoLight) on a UIBarButton item, short of creating it as an image (I'm pretty clumsy when it comes to Photoshop)?

Are the images available to address somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use - (id)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView and pass it a UIButton.  UIButton is a UIView